# Is there any way to atomize prisma Models, to not have too much code in the schema.prisma

Tags: prisma

I want to know if is there some way to keep each prisma Model in a single file and then export each Model to the schema.prisma file

```
export model User {
    id                  Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
    name                String   @db.VarChar(255)
    last_name           String   @db.VarChar(255)
    dateOf_birth        DateTime @db.Date()
}
```

and then

```
import {User} from 'User.prisma'

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User
```

so I can keep each model or table in individual file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible natively to split the `schema.prisma` file into multiple files.

You could use the [Aurora](https://github.com/sabinadams/aurora) tool to split the schema files.